# Function with two equations for different domains

Tags: python, function, dns, sympy

I tried to define a function that has the form H_0*(1-x/L) if -L < x < L and is equal to zero if x is outside of this domain. 
I tried using an if-else loop but got the error "TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational".
Answers to similar questions available online did not help me to solve my problem.

I need to plot this function H(x) then later with sympy, so the solution has to be capable of doing that.

Thanks so much for any help!

```
import numpy as np
import math
import sympy as sym

H_0 = int(input("Enter H_0: "))
L = int(input("Enter L: "))  
x = sym.Symbol("x")

def boundaries(x):
    if -L < x < L:
        in_boundaries = True
    else:
        in_boundaries = False

def H(x):
    boundaries(x)
    if in_boundaries == True:
        return H_0 * (1 - x/L)
    else:
        return 0



print("\nH(x) = " + str(H(x)))
```

Comment: Since x is a symbol it is not possible to determine if `-L < x < L`. If you want a symbolic relational there you can use `(-L < x) & (x < L)` but the if will still lead to the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

`in_boundaries` is a local variable, so you can't see it from outside `boundaries`.

If you change `boundaries` to:

```
def boundaries(x):
    if -L < x < L:
       return True
    return False
```

and then in the next function set `in_boundaries = boundaries(x)` you should be fine.

Comment: Hi Igor, do you mean like that? Because I still get the same error :(                              ```def boundaries(x):
    if -L < x < L:
        return True
    return False

def H(x):
    in_boundaries = boundaries(x)
    if in_boundaries == True:
        return H_0 * (1 - x/L) 
    else:
        return 0```

Comment: @slothlover In your final line, there is no numerical value assigned to x, which is why it bombs now. I don't know if you want to pass `H_0`, or...

Comment: Hello Igor, do you mean what the program uses for x in the H_0*(1-x/L) function? I wanted to use the function later for a graph so would ideally set that x goes between a minimum of -L and max of L (or similar boundaries). Is that possible? Thanks for your help

Comment: @slothlover I mean the final `print`, which evaluates the function at `x`, which is not assigned.

Comment: Hi Igor, as in e.g. print(H(2)) if x = 2 after the if-else loop? If yes, I still get the same mistake. I am sorry, I just really do not know why it does not work.